# Removing entire row with specific values in cells of excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Suppose I have 10 excel files in a directory, and I want to iterate over them and remove rows of each excel which meet certain conditions like (if cell contains values like null), and save the updated file and move that updated file into a new directory. I have to only remove the rows not the columns
How can I achieve this with python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to have a look at [Pandas DataFrame](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe/). There you can easily [import](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and [export](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_excel)  from Excel-files.

In your code you would iterate with a for loop over your files and [remove](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)   the desired rows from your read-in DataFrames and export them to the Excel-files again.

I have written a semi-Pseudo code for you. Hope this helps. Store this code in the folder of your xlsx-files.

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil



#create a new folder if not exists:
if not os.path.exists("New"):
os.makedirs("New")

# store all files in a list
filenames = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

#iterate through your files
for file in filenames:

    #create dataframes from your files
    df = pd.read_excel (file ) 

    #insert some conditions:
    #...
    #...
    #...
    #...

    #e.g. get specific value
    #val=df.iloc[0,1]

    #Drop the matching rows from your df e.g.
    df.drop(df.index[0])

    #write to excel files
    df.to_excel(file,index=None)

    # move updated files to that folder
    shutil.move(file, "New/" + file)

    print (df)
```

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, if it helped you out.